# Removing div created from PHP using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How do I use jquery to remove this div tag created in php? Specifically, After pressing the delete button I want to remove one div. I have several.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
// For each book...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<div class="task-list" id="div_'.$row['uid'].'"><table>';
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><b>".$row['title']."</b></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>".$row['author']."</td></tr>";
echo '<tr><td><img src="'.$row['image_url'].'" width="50" height="100" /></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><button class="btn cmt_list" name="cmtList" id="cmt- '.$row['uid'].'"value = "hide/show"/>Show</button> </td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><button class="btn btn-danger delete_bk" name="deleteItem" id="'.$row['uid'].'" />Delete</button></td></tr>';
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

This is my javascript:

```
//deleting a book from DB when user clicks "Delete" button
$(".delete_bk").on("click", function() {
    var book_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
        url: "delete_bk.php",
            data: {book_id: book_id}
    })
    .done(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#div_'+id).remove();
    alert("Data deleted");
        });
});
```

Comment: you wan to remove the div#bookdiv of particular record?

Comment: yes! if I were to have created #div_1 and #div_2, and I want to delete #div_2, what would be the jquery function to delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
$(".delete_bk").on("click", function() {
var book_id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "delete_bk.php",
        data: {book_id: book_id},
        success:function(){
             $('#div_'+book_id).remove();
             alert("Data deleted");

       }
  })
});
```

Comment: hmm doesn't seem to be working. any tips on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Which div you would delete?

In jQuery you can simply do:

```
$(div_to_remove).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#deletebtnid").click(function(e){

$("#divid").remove();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.task-list').remove();
```

and if you just want to remove the first div:

```
$('.task-list').first().remove();
```

you can add the following code somewhere in your html:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { $('.task-list').remove(); });
</script
```

Note:

> start with . for class names and # for ids to find elements in jQuery.
>   Example: $('.YOURCLASSNAME') or $('#YOURID')

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_bk', function(){
    $('#bookdiv').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_bk', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#div_'+id).remove();
    });
```

Here in line,

```
<div class="task-list" id="bookdiv"><table>
```

you need to apply ID like

```
<div class="task-list" id="div_'.$row['uid'].'"><table>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems that you have the id "bookdiv" more that once - **html ids have to be unique**... change div -> add a data-attribute like `data-delete="$id_of_your_div"` to your button and then:

**Example**

Html:

```
<div class="bookdiv task-list" id="book-5813">
```

Button:

```
<button class="delete_bk" ... data-delete="#book-5813" />
```

Delete JS

```
$(document).on('click','.delete_bk', function(){
   var delete = $(this).data('delete');
    $(delete).remove();
});
```